# "a bit of overkill"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I have the following sentence:

> Lemma 2 is **a bit overkill** for proving Lemma 3

I want to show that the proof of Lemma 3 hasn't used the full strength of Lemma 2. But I feel uncomfortable for above sentence. Any suggestions?

Comment: Struggling for context here, but just by parsing the sentence, I do believe you need, "...is a bit *of* overkill for..."

Comment: "Lemma 2 is a bit *of an* overkill for proving Lemma 3" seems like the way I would say it (AmE). Your example could be a shortened form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Overkill" and "a bit" are going in opposite directions:

**It was a bit of overkill to swat that fly with a hammer.**

That's admissible if you want to have an ironic tone. But if you don't want to introduce such a tone,  a less casual phrase that avoids the irony would be

> Lemma 2 is ample proof of lemma 3.

Comment: Thank you! This might be a stupid question, but should we have "Lemma 2 is 'an' ample proof of Lemma 3"?

Comment: I think you're right that "an" is an improvement here. Evidence can be "ample proof" of something, but lemma 2 is not evidence but a theorem in an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is something that would probably be **spoken**

> P1: What do you think about using Lemma2 to prove Lemma 3?
>   P2: That's **a bit overkill**

meaning that it is **excessive**.  Using the idiom **a bit** makes it informal.

The meaning implies more than just the **full strength** not being used, it's saying that not even a **small fraction** of the strength is necessary.